# AWS Athena alb logs: getting max hits per minute to the request url each day

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena, presto, amazon-elb

I am trying to get the max hits (throughput) per minute to the request URLs for each day from the alb logs. I used the table projections to partition the table. Trying to figure out the query to get the desired result for max hits per minute for all the urls for last 1-3 years.
The result should look like this (just a sample, the timestamp can be in any format)

| Timestamp | Url | Max Hits Per Min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-29-2019 8:01 AM | url1 | 10720 |
| 12-29-2019 10:35 AM | url2 | 21329 |
| 12-29-2019 10:35 AM | url3 | 37420 |
| 12-30-2019 11:53 AM | url1 | 5898 |
| 12-30-2019 01:30 PM | url2 | 14230 |
| 12-30-2019 05:19 PM | url3 | 20000 |

The table creation query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alb_logs (
        type string,
        time string,
        elb string,
        client_ip string,
        client_port int,
        target_ip string,
        target_port int,
        request_processing_time double,
        target_processing_time double,
        response_processing_time double,
        elb_status_code string,
        target_status_code string,
        received_bytes bigint,
        sent_bytes bigint,
        request_verb string,
        request_url string,
        request_proto string,
        user_agent string,
        ssl_cipher string,
        ssl_protocol string,
        target_group_arn string,
        trace_id string,
        domain_name string,
        chosen_cert_arn string,
        matched_rule_priority string,
        request_creation_time string,
        actions_executed string,
        redirect_url string,
        lambda_error_reason string,
        target_port_list string,
        target_status_code_list string,
        classification string,
        classification_reason string
        )
        PARTITIONED BY ( `partition_date` string)
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        'serialization.format' = '1',
        'input.regex' = 
    '([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([-.0-9]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^\s]+?)\" \"([^\s]+)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\"')
        LOCATION 's3://your-alb-logs-directory/AWSLogs/<ACCOUNT-ID>/elasticloadbalancing/<REGION>/';
        TBLPROPERTIES ('projection.enabled'='true', 
        'projection.partition_date.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
        'projection.partition_date.interval'='1', 
        'projection.partition_date.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
        'projection.partition_date.range'='2018/01/01,NOW', 
        'projection.partition_date.type'='date', 
        'storage.location.template'='s3://your-alb-logs-directory/AWSLogs/<ACCOUNT-ID>/elasticloadbalancing/<REGION>/${partition_date}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
with cte as (
   select date_trunc('minute',timestamp) as minute, url, count(*) as hits_per_minute from mytable
group by 1,2
)
select max_by(minute, hits_per_minute) as timestamp, url, max(hits_per_minute) from cte
group by date_trunc('day', minute), url
```

Explanation:
The common table expression (`cte`) will calculate the number of hits per minute per url, from which you then extract the minute where the max hits is reached (using the `max_by` function) and the max hits, grouped by `day` and `url`.

See the docs for:

- `max_by` function: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#id2
- `date_trunc` function: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: It worked. I also used from_iso8601_timestamp(time)  Further help if you can provide regarding getting the similar type of URLs  as one result instead of multiple rows. E.g. request_urls like below https://abc:443/xyz/getprofle/123
https://abc:443/xyz/getprofle/456
https://abc:443/xyz/getprofle/789 are showing separately as they are distinct. I just want these grouped together. e.g. https://abc:443/xyz/getprofle as one result